# Why are these CSS files being downloaded twice?

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching, cookies

I have included all the files just once. I have triple checked it. Here are some screen shots. I noticed that the request headers are different. How do I resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

```
<?php require_once("cssheadertop.php");?>
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="">
<link rel=stylesheet href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab'>
<style>.demo{text-align:center}</style>
<title>My title</title>
<?php require_once("cssheaderbottom.php")?>
```

This is cssheadertop.php

```
<?php require_once('../../templates/sitelink.php');?>
<link rel=stylesheet href=//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.2/united/bootstrap.min.css>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel=stylesheet href=../../rrssb.css />
<script src=../../rrssb.min.js></script>
<link rel=stylesheet href=../../style.css>
<link rel=stylesheet href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:300|Orbitron:900'>
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js></script>
<script src=../prism.js></script>
<link rel=stylesheet href=../prism.css />
<meta property=og:image content="">
```

**UPDATE**
sitelink.php just has PHP and cssheaderbottom.php just has navigation.

**UPDATE 2**
It is not just about bootstrap.min.css but every css file is being downloaded twice sometime thrice (You can see it in the images below).

Comment: Are you including it twice in your HTML?

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?

Comment: No I am not. I have checked it multiple times

Comment: I am inlcuding the html now please wait.

Comment: maybe some other stylesheet use @import and load bootstarp for second time? just use search by all files with "bootstrap.min.css"

Comment: It is not just about bootstrap.min.css but every css file is being downloaded twice sometime thrice.

Comment: You probably put the same `<?php require_once();?>` statement both in your shared site header as in some, if not many, of your server pages.

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with your code, it has to do with your browser development setup, there is an option somewhere in your development console that is called 'Persist logs' that basically keep old files in the logs for you to compare, if you disable that feature you'll see that there is no load duplication of files, see my attached screen shot where i duplicate your problem by selecting the 'Persist logs' -marked in yellow
hope it helped you,

[image: Persist logs].